# RSpec Controller Test for Pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, pagination

I'm adding some controller tests to make sure my pagination works correctly. I use the gemfile "Will-paginate", which automatically adds pagination at 30 users. In this test I add 31 users and look for the selector but the error I'm getting tells me that the pagination never appears. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks guys!

HAML:

```
= will_paginate @users, :class => 'pagination'
```

user_controller_spec.rb

```
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

describe 'GET #index' do
    before { get :index }

    it { should respond_with(200) }
    it { should render_template('index') }
    it { should render_with_layout('application') }
    it { should use_before_action(:authorize_user!) }

    it 'shows pagination' do
      users = FactoryGirl.create_list(:user, 31)
      expect(:index).to have_css('div.pagination')
    end
  end
```

Error:

```
1) Admin::UsersController GET #index shows pagination
 Failure/Error: expect(:index).to have_css('div.pagination')
   expected to find css "div.pagination" but there were no matches
```

Comment: Verify if you have actually 31 user `expect(User.count).to eq 31`, if you got it right the links will show
`

Comment: Hi Marwen, 

Helpful comment. Thanks! It confirms there are 35 users (I create a few before as well)      

Failure/Error: expect(User.count).to eq 31
       
       expected: 31
            got: 35

So there are 35 users and it should show the pagination?

Comment: Problem is that the test still fails

Comment: Install this `launchy` gem and put this line before the expectation: `save_and_open_page`, a webpage will launch with the view of page you are testing, that way you can find what's going wrong.

Comment: Mmm. Cannot get it to work. I'll have to keep trying. Thanks Marwen

Answer (score -1):

The previous and now deleted answer had it right. You need to create the users before you do the `get`. The problem with both your question and the other answer is the use of `let` to create users, which lazily evaluates. Try it with `let!` for defining the users or by putting the creation of users inside a `before`, as in the following, which also uses `subject` to keep the setup separate from the code under test.

```
describe 'GET #index' do
    before { FactoryGirl.create(:user, 31) }

    subject { get :index }

    it { should respond_with(200) }
    it { should render_template('index') }
    it { should render_with_layout('application') }
    it { should use_before_action(:authorize_user!) }

    it 'shows pagination' do
      expect(:index).to have_css('div.pagination')
    end
  end
end
```